# Множество кнопок в custom view

Tags: android

Я сделал custom view который представляет граф. Каждая вершина по задумке должна быть кнопкой или воспринимать клик по экрану. Количество вершин зависит от графа. Как сделать так, чтобы вершины обрабатывали клик?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перегружаете

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){...}
```

Перебираете в цикле ваши точки графа, заполняете некий Rect с центром в точке, "раздвигаете" его на некую дельту в зависимости от размера экрана (~8dp).
Проверка "попадания" и выполнение действия.

```
if( rect.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY()) ){
   ...
}
```